# RED 5 video server on Android mobile phone... Is there any Open Source port?

Tags: java, android, flv, red5

RED 5 video server on Android mobile phone... Is there any Open Source port project? So like simple opensource live Camera Video \ Audio encoding to FLV... I need such Opensource project to create Android live video streaming client for my server (I want to encode video on clients into FLV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really can see why you would want to run Red5 on Android. I am a core developer for Red5 and I can tell you this would probably be very difficult to accomplish, I suggest that if you want an flash media server on your device that you go the native route and start with something like crtmpserver ( http://www.rtmpd.com/ ) or mammoth ( http://mammothserver.org/ ).

Answer (score 1):

crtmpserver is 100% functional on android with all its features:

- RTMP and friends (RTMPE, RTMPT, RTMPTE, RTMPS)
- LiveFLV
- able to ingest RTSP and spit out RTMP (alpha stage, wait for a few days, because I'm in my vacation)
- able to stream RTMP streams over RTSP (acts like a RTSP server)
- **HIGHLY** customizable. You can add new protocols in no-time
- RTMFP is under development :)

Cheers,
Andrei